# Why we need Samadhi to attain enlightement?

Tags: enlightenment, samadhi, wisdom

Why we need Samadhi to attain enlightement ?

Do people with better samadhi can think more than the people with less within short amount of time ?

> experiment of people with low IQ, and high IQ, put them in the same room, and you give them the same job. Rob a bank. You’ll find out that the low IQ people probably do a much better job of robbing a bank, plotting the bank robbery, than high IQ people, who get all messed up with legal implications and stuff like that. - Michio Kaku

Is widom something like that ? What is the connection between samadhi and wisdom ?

Answer (score 3):

> Is widom something like that ? What is the connection between samadhi and wisdom ?

There's a big difference between wisdom and being book-smart. If you have a fish tank full of muddy water, and if you constantly shaking it, will you be able to see through the tank and detect the objects on the other side? How about letting the tank settle on a solid level ground for a while, then see through it? [Sila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threefold_Training) is that solid level ground. Samadhi is the "settling" of the tank, Wisdom (or penetrating insight) is the "seeing through" to the other side.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in the dark with a touch with shaky hands can not focus it in a particular direction, then you cannot make out what lies ahead clearly. Samadhi helps you steady your mind on one object to see it clearly like steadings your hands and focusing your touch on a particular object of interest like a snake on the path.

Answer (score 2):

Wisdom and immersion (i.e., samadhi) are only two of the three practice categories. Let's look at all three.

The three practice categories are *wisdom, ethics, and immersion*. The Noble Eightfold Path defines the right practice in each of these three categories.

We start first with the practice of right wisdom:

> [MN44:11.5](https://suttacentral.net/mn44/en/sujato#mn44:11.5): Right view and right thought: these things are included in the category of wisdom.”

With that beginning of right wisdom, we can then practice right ethics:

> [MN44:11.3](https://suttacentral.net/mn44/en/sujato#mn44:11.3): Right speech, right action, and right livelihood: these things are included in the category of ethics.

And eventually we are able to practice right immersion:

> [MN44:11.4](https://suttacentral.net/mn44/en/sujato#mn44:11.4): Right effort, right mindfulness, and right immersion: these things are included in the category of immersion.

The practice of right immersion yields greater insight which helps wisdom grow. In this way, the three right practices circle around and strengthen each other.

Together, the three right practice categories span the Noble Eightfold Path and give us more light to make our way in a life clouded by the darkness of ignorance.